Where this error 'memory allocation failed, out of memory' originates from?
I am developing a program on Solana and also testing few aspects regarding how solana enforces checks on the bpf program. However, I am stuck with the issue that I am getting the error 'memory allocation failed, out of memory' which I believe is coming because I am exhausting the 32KB heap memory available in Solana however,I am not able to find the root where this error is being thrown. I have checked the complete Solana codebase, as well as the solana rbpf cli. However, haven't found anywhere that throws the above error specifically.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Nope. I was using native rust program. But Jon answer is exactly what I was looking for

The root of the error actually comes from the allocator -- when there's no more heap memory, the allocator returns a null pointer at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/dc8dd333241ae37ff676d5743c348c9e0f13e144/sdk/program/src/entrypoint.rs#L251
And then (I think) the standard library will print the memory during a failed allocation at https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/2d5a628a1de1d38318909a710ef37da6251e362e/library/alloc/src/collections/mod.rs#L136
